# Why is the Connection header not being set on my HttpListener response?

Tags: c#, websocket

I am attempting to create a C# web socket server - I know this is re-inventing the wheel a little bit but its more of a coding excercise than for a real-life application.

I have created the Listener and am able to recieve requests, I have read the spec for websockets and have managed to setup the initial headers for the handshake, but i cannot seem to set the "Connection" header?

Here is the code i am using upon recieving a request and validating it is a new websocket upgrade handshake;

```
string wsGuid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
string retCon = ctx.Request.Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"] + wsGuid;
Console.WriteLine("Upgrade, key recieved: " + ctx.Request.Headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"]);
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 s = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] retBy = s.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(retCon));
string retStr = Convert.ToBase64String(retBy);
Console.WriteLine("Return string: " + retStr);
ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Accept", retStr);
ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Upgrade", "WebSocket");
ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "Upgrade");
ctx.Response.StatusCode = 101;
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

This works fine, but when i attempt to open a websocket connection in javascript running on chrome i get the error
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4455/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing`

Upon inspecting the response headers in Fiddler i can see the response looks like this;

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: WebSocket
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: k3N0odnsp2f9eanXsFN7EILQExo=
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 12:30:05 GMT
EndTime: 13:30:05.865
ReceivedBytes: 0
SentBytes: 0
```

which of course is infact missing the Connection header, even though i specified to add it in the C# code? What is going on here, am i adding headers wrong or am i unable to modify the Connection header using this method?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're going down a bad trail here. You're working with a `Response` object that expects to send headers/body once and then nothing else can happen with it. Even if you succeed in setting the Connection header, you're going to end up terminating the connection without ever being able to send/receive data over the "Web Socket" (Because the `Request` object isn't going to pull any further data and the `Response` object won't accept any more data)

Comment: Is there a better implementation you can suggest?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx